# How can I manage QWebView contents in Qt?

Tags: qt, http, qwebview, qwebpage

I have a QWebView object loading a web page. I need to save a picture from the page to the memory. The URL of the picture is dynamic, but it follows a regexp.

How do I do that with QWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can't save image with `QWebView`. But you might be interested in `QWebFrame::toHtml`, using which you can obtain all the content in HTML.
Then you need to regexp to obtain image URL, fetch it, and finally save it. Solution is [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?192171-Loading-img-from-URL).